# How to calculate mean of specific column month wise with years?

Tags: awk

I have CSV file having temperature data of `April` and `May` months for six years. I want to calculate mean of every month with each year. I am using `awk` command but it shows 0 output. I don't know how to use awk command for this problem. I am using this script for the problem;

```
  $ mawk ' NR>1 { split($5,d,"/"); s[d[3]"/"d[1]]+=$6; c[d[3]"/"d[1]]++;
  } END { for (i in s) print i, s[i]/c[i]; }' DELHI_IMD1618.csv
```

The input fragment:

```
Stn ID Lat     Long time(GMT) DATE TEMPERATURE
IMDE1615_14164F(NAJAFGARH),28.63,77.01,2,04/01/2012,32
IMDE1615_14164F(NAJAFGARH),28.63,77.01,15,04/04/2012,32.7
IMDE1615_14164F(NAJAFGARH),28.63,77.01,6,05/01/2012,35.2
IMDE1615_14164F(NAJAFGARH),28.63,77.01,7,05/01/2012,36
IMDE1615_14164F(NAJAFGARH),28.63,77.01,8,05/01/2012,36.1
IMDE1615_14164F(NAJAFGARH),28.63,77.01,0,04/02/2013,28.7
IMDE1615_14164F(NAJAFGARH),28.63,77.01,1,04/02/2013,28.6
```

I want output like this

```
04/2013 mean
05/2013 mean
04/2014 mean
```

Comment: You can't get that output from your posted sample input. Fix it so we aren't guessing.

Answer (score 0):

***gawk*** solution:

```
awk -F, 'NR>1{ split($5,a,"/"); k=a[1]"/"a[3]; data[k]["c"]++;  data[k]["s"]+=$6 }
         END{ for(i in data) print i,data[i]["s"]/data[i]["c"] }' DELHI_IMD1618.csv
```

The exemplary output (for your input fragment):

```
05/2012 35.7667
04/2012 32.35
04/2013 28.65
```

---

*Details*:

- `-F,` - field separator
- `split($5,a,"/")` - split "*date*" column by `/`
- `k=a[1]"/"a[3]` - forming compound key for associative array (i.e. `"04/2012"`)
- `data[k]["c"]++` - incrementing the number of grouped items (`"c"` - "count")
- `data[k]["s"]+=$6` - accumulating *temperature* column values
- `data[i]["s"]/data[i]["c"]` - calculating average value

Comment: the date format is mm/dd/yyyy, when i run the above script it show error like this .                                                                                                awk: line 1: syntax error at or near [
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near [
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near [

Comment: @VaibhavKumar, with standard awk implementation it will surely work

Comment: The script is gawk-only due to true multi-dimenstional arrays syntax. You need`array["foo","bar"]` instead of `array["foo"]["bar"]` syntax (plus some tweaks) for it to work in any awk.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[,/]" }
NR==1 { next }
{ date=$5"/"$7 }
date != prev { prtMean(); prev=date }
{ sum+=$8; cnt++ }
END { prtMean() }

function prtMean() {
    if (cnt) {
        print prev, sum / cnt
        sum = cnt = 0
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
04/2012 32.35
05/2012 35.7667
04/2013 28.65
```

Comment: won't work if the 1st field contains slash like `IMDE1615_14164F(N/AJAFGARH)`

Comment: nor if contains a comma or a newline or... but none of those are present in the posted samples and I doubt if they will be in the real data so no point trying to handle cases that don't exist. The OP can always fix his sample if it's an issue.